# comparison of two file using bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I need following code in linux bash:

Step 1:

run a command and create file1
run a command and create file2

compare file1 and 2

if any difference go to step 1 (keep trying 4 times, if no success, abort program)
else continue.

now I'm stuck with this comparison and then if loop and iterations. i know diff and comm can be used but unable to understand, How as i dont want any particular output and then how to manage these 4 iterations. can anyone please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the temporary files.  Here's a version that give you a function to use to gather the "attempt" concept into a single success or fail to write more code around:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd_1="$1"
cmd_2="$2"

iterate () {
    for attempt in {1..4} ; do
        echo attempt $attempt
        if diff  <($cmd_1) <($cmd_2) >/dev/null ; then
            return   # still has the diff's successful exit status
        fi
    done
    false
}

if iterate ; then
    echo successful
else
    echo aborted ; false  # propagate failure status out of script
fi

#---eof
```

I stuffed that into `./foo` and made it executable and tested with:

```
$ ./foo 'cat foo' 'cat foo' 
attempt 1
successful
$ ./foo 'cat foo' 'cat /dev/null' 
attempt 1
attempt 2
attempt 3
attempt 4
aborted
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if cmp -s "$a" "$b"; then
    echo Same
else
    echo Differ
fi
```

or you could use diff
   if diff "$file_a" "$file_b" &> /dev/null ; then
    echo "Files are the same"
   else
    echo "Files differ"
   fi

Comment: but i also need to iterate 4 times in case of difference. i think it would require nested if.